# Basic VB troubles

Tags: vba, field, calculator, arcgis

I'm simply wondering what symbol/character I can use to define any character in a string...

Basically I have a number of records with RR 2, RR#2, RR1, RR 1, etc. and I want to use a symbol that will define anything after the RR and replace it with nothing "". I know in SQL it's the "%" symbol, but not sure in VBA.

I am using the Replace function in ArcGIS field calculator.

I tried searching but cannot come up with the right question to find the answer I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want a single character or 1 to n characters?

Comment: I'm not sure... I figured VB would have a symbol to use so that I could put. ({Replace} CityProv, "RR%", "") something like that except the percent symbol does not work as I have tried..

Comment: You need some string replacement function in VB? or ArcGIS? which?

Comment: which part(s) of the original string do you want to keep/extract? anything before/after RR, any (numerical) data following 'RR*' ?

Comment: ArcGIS field calculator uses VBA so I removed the VB.Net tag

Comment: Do you only want RR? If so, why not Left function? Or do you want RR1,RR2, so only remove anything that is not a number, or is not 1 or 2? I note that your example includes RR1.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unclear if you want VBA or VB.Net,

Here's a VBA answer just use the ChopString function using the format shown in the Test sub:

```
Function ChopString(str As String, after As String, Optional caseInsensitive As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim x As Long
    If caseInsensitive Then
        x = InStr(1, str, after, vbTextCompare)
    Else
        x = InStr(1, str, after, vbBinaryCompare)
    End If
    If x Then
        str = Left(str, x + Len(after) - 1)
    End If
    ChopString = str
End Function
Sub Test()
    Dim OriginalString As String
    Dim choppedString As String
    OriginalString = "1234RR this will be chopped"
    choppedString = ChopString(OriginalString, "RR")
    MsgBox choppedString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the .net `REPLACE()` function doesn't support wildcard characters, you can use a function as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/30e65c77-6795-402c-9717-bd8d07a534e3/) but it's a bit long winded.

Comment: This is VB.Net. OP did not know, but the question is about VBA (ArcGIS field calculator uses VBA)